# visual studio extension to execute sql

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, plugins

I have several .sql files in my visual studio 2010 project.

I am looking for an extension or add on where I can right click on the sql file and execute its contents against a sql server database.

Anyone know if such an extension exists?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with SQL Server Denali (at least in the community preview version I installed to play with), SQL Management Studio is integrated into the Visual Studio 2010 IDE. So you get all the syntax highlighting, Object Explorer, etc., all from within VS2010.

That said, I didn't specifically try adding a SQL script to an existing project (and I uninstalled the shared features last week because there were... issues), but with such a tight integration, I assume doing more or less what you're asking for is the intention.