# How to run sql script from the solution explorer in Visual Studio 2013 or 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2008 solution containing a "database project". From there I can run .sql files, by right-clicking them, like this:

[image: db project - vs2008 solution]

However, I imported this project to both Visual Studio 2010 (resulting in a `.dbproj` file) and VS2013 (ending `.sqlproj` file), and now I cannot find that option anymore.

Also, I can't figure out how to add a database reference to my production server, just like I used to do.

I did try to create a new project in these newer versions as well, but no good.

So, two questions. First, how to add my db reference, and second, how to run the .sql script under that reference?

**Edit** A fellow coworker also has this same issue: [How to create a database project in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654286/how-to-create-a-database-project-in-visual-studio-2013)

**Edit2** Tried this from msdn: [How to: Run SQL Scripts in Solution Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/yea4bc1b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but no success. The "Run" and "Run On" options aren't there, and dragging the script to the database reference didn't work as well.

[image]

Also found the following related question: [visual studio extension to execute sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519831/visual-studio-extension-to-execute-sql?rq=1)

Comment: What happened when you tried to create a project? Did you have SSDT installed?

Comment: What happens if you open the .sql file? Can you execute it?

Comment: @JohnSaunders There's a "Execute" option if I open it and right-click inside the editor, in vs2013 (shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+E`). However, doing that for my hundreds of sql files will be a real pain.

Comment: Why are you executing hundreds of SQL files by right-clicking in Solution Explorer?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Because this is a solution for my company's website, and the database project is meant to contain change scripts that we (the developers) create regularly. For example, creating and altering tables and stored procedures. Once every few months we publish the website in production. Also, ocasionally we'll re-create local databases.

Comment: VS2013 SQL project let you manage database project as model instead of branch of scripts. DACPAC will create change script for you. If you want to execute a number of scripts, why don't you create script file, reference all other scripts and execute it from sqlcmd?

Comment: @qxg Well, if I had it so easy in VS 2008, why should I go through that way now? Doesn't seem right for me. If it's the last option ok, but I find it hard to believe. If that feature is gone for good, there must be an alternative, at least.

Comment: I have the same problem.  In VS 2013, Entity Framework (EF) models and scripts are generated within different types of projects--this is not just about SQL projects.  Tutorials and formal documentation for EF mention running the generated scripts but don't say how.  There should be some way of doing this easily and directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Project, do you have the "SQL Server Database Project" available?

Have you tried the solution [in this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a050d6a7-d7e0-46df-abf6-df156a35bd3b/vs-2013-cannot-open-sqlproj-project)?

[image]

Comment: He isn't trying to create a new database he wants to import a database or run a script on one.

Comment: Sure, but he still needs to have this project type installed or the project converter won't recognize the DTS project type